# Excel VBA Solver Error (specificly integer constraint)

Tags: excel, vba, integer, constraints, solver

Sorry if my english grammatically is not correct (I am not from UK or USA). I try to set up the Excel solver while using VBA code. So far, this is the macro I set up:

```
Sub solver()

SolverReset

SolverAdd CellRef:="$G$32", Relation:=2, FormulaText:="$I$32"
SolverAdd CellRef:="$G$95", Relation:=3, FormulaText:="$I$95"
SolverAdd CellRef:="$G$96", Relation:=1, FormulaText:="$I$96"
SolverAdd CellRef:="$G$128", Relation:=3, FormulaText:="$I$128"
SolverAdd CellRef:="$G$129", Relation:=1, FormulaText:="$I$129"

SolverOk SetCell:="$C$2", MaxMinVal:=2, ValueOf:=0, ByChange:="C4:I31", _
Engine:=2, EngineDesc:="Simplex LP"

SolverAdd CellRef:="$C$4:$I$31", Relation:=4, FormulaText:="integer"

SolverSolve True
End Sub
```

However, with this code I get problems with the integer constraint because the solver still gives decimal numbers for the decision variables. Does anyone know what's going wrong here?

I already added in the solver from options -> add-ins. I also checked the VBA editor -> references

Answer (score 0):

Haven't used solver for almost 20 years, but MS Documentation for SolverAdd is as follows:

> SolverAdd( CellRef, Relation, FormulaText)
>
> CellRef Required Variant. A reference to a cell or a range of cells
> that forms the left side of a constraint. Relation Required Integer.
> The arithmetic relationship between the left and right sides of the
> constraint. **If you choose 4, 5, or 6, CellRef must refer to decision
> variable cells, and FormulaText should not be specified.**

In your example, you are choosing 4 and also specifying FormulaText?

Also not sure if that is the problem, sorry if irrelevant.

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply.I'm positive the CellRef refer to the decision variable cells. I just tried to omitte the FormulaText from the code but I still get the decimal numbers in the decision variable cells.

Answer (score 0):

Just found the solution. I used:

```
SolverSolve True
```

This has to be:

```
SolverSolve
```

Apparently Excel makes the decision, by giving `True`, to still give a decimal number solution. Can someone please verify this?

Answer (score 0):

For the Solver, you can record a Macro to do whatever you need to do. Change the ranges to be dynamic, if necessary, and you will have what you need. You can learn how to make ranges dynamic from the link below.

https://www.thespreadsheetguru.com/blog/2014/7/7/5-different-ways-to-find-the-last-row-or-last-column-using-vba